# How do I sort the user model by fields in the profile model (1: 1)?

Tags: python, django

skill_note_reputation is a field in the Profile model that has a 1: 1 relationship with Profileuser.

How do I sort user models by skill_note_reputation values?

```
    user_list = User.objects.all ()
```

Thanks for letting me know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `parent_link=True` key to your `OneToOneField`, you can reference fields in the `Profileuser` as if they belonged to the `User` model.

For example:

```
class Profileuser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
          User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
          related_name='profileuser', parent_link=True)
    skill_note_reputation = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, you can filter your `User` model like this:

```
User.objects.filter(skill_note_reputation=1)
```

For a more *pythonic* approach, you can take advantage of Django's [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), and turn your `Profileuser` model into this:

```
class Profileuser(User):
    skill_note_reputation = models.IntegerField()
```

Note that this model and the above model are identical.

If for some reason you don't want to do use `parent_link=True`, you can reference any `ForeignKey` columns using Django's `LOOKUP_SEP`, like this:

```
User.objects.filter(profileuser__skill_note_reputation=1)
```

Comment: problem is sloved The problem wasn't solved for at least a few days.thank you for telling me